# How to use MathJax in a question?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I am puzzled by how does one create a question with MathJax in it. I do not know how to use MathJax and I am asking now for help regarding this situation. Thank you.

Comment: When you're composing a question, there's a block on the right side of the screen with formatting help, it contains a mathjax example and a link to more mathjax help.

Comment: A related (new) FAQ: [A brief guide to MathJax for PSE users](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7421/44357)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply include the MathJax between dollar signs (`$`), like so:

```
blah blah $\sum_{x=0}^{100}(x)$ blah
```

> blah blah $\sum_{x=0}^{100}(x)$ blah

If you want the MathJax to be displayed as its own block, rather than inline, use two dollar signs:

```
$$\sum_{x=0}^{100}(x)$$
```

> $$\sum_{x=0}^{100}(x)$$

For a comprehensive tutorial, see [this post on meta.Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/65867).